# Help with Sentence Structure and Grammar

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

The following Federal dispatch case requested did not qualify for an automated dispatch creation. Please create the dispatch manually.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, welcome to EL&U. You haven't edited your question as @KJO suggested, and as you haven't identified a specific source of concern in the text, regrettably I'm flagging this question for closure as "off-topic (proofreading)". For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Following** and **requested** are clashing with each other.

I guess it is either of the following:

- The **following** Federal dispatch case did not qualify for an
  automated dispatch creation. Please create the dispatch manually.
- The **requested** Federal dispatch case did not qualify for an
  automated dispatch creation. Please create the dispatch manually.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the other answer. There is no reason why *following* and *requested* are mutually exclusive.

It's quite possible that you can have multiple dispatches, some of which were requested by a particular person and others which were not, some of which can be created automatically and others which cannot.

When looking at a particular dispatch, you might say to somebody who has asked about it:

> The following Federal dispatch case *that you requested* did not qualify for an automated dispatch creation. Please create the dispatch manually.

Expressing the same thing in simpler terms:

> The following requested Federal dispatch case did not qualify for automatic creation. Please create it it manually.

---

Of course, you *can* remove both of those words and simplify it even more:

> Your Federal dispatch case didn't qualify for automatic creation. Please create it manually.